# Issue including QT files in VSCode Manjaro Linux

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I have been working with c++ for a few years now and I have decided to try my hands at simple GUI development.  I know that c++ is not generally regarded as a great language to do GUI development, but I am very comfortable with it and have had success using c++ with QT Creator at making simple GUIs.  I have seen people running QT code on Visual Studio Code and I am currently trying to set it up for myself.  I looked around on the internet for some guides or at least some instruction, but what little I found was either outdated or designed for a different os (I use Manjaro Linux).  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/qt6/**",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

game.h (Auto-generated QT code from starting a project)

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Game; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Game : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Game(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Game();

private:
    Ui::Game *ui;
};
#endif // GAME_H
```

The error I am getting: `cannot open source file "QMainWindow"` on line 4 of game.h.

I tried to address the problem by adding `/usr/include/qt6` to my configurations file, but that didn't help anything.  I am sure this is a fairly simple include issue, so thank you for your patience!

Comment: I assume you have checked to make sure QMainWindow is indeed in /usr/include/qt6?

Comment: @user4581301 yes, I ran `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_HEADERS` in console to determine where the header files should be located and received `/usr/include/qt6`

Comment: Groovy. Here's a shot in the dark: VS Code splits the intellisence and compiler instructions into different files and different structures. If you only specified the include folder in one of these configurations, the other may still be missing out and generating errors.

Comment: I checked every file I could think of and they are all up to date ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. There are three main configuration files for C++ in VS Code. One of then sets up the compiler and build tools. Another sets up the IDE's rapid feedback tool, Intellisense. I've seen many questions where the source of the error is the include path or library path or some other important bit of information has been added to one of the config files, but not to both.

Comment: @user4581301 I manually checked my /usr/include directory, and while I did find qt6, I never found a `QMainWindow` file/directory anywhere.  I have also checked `usr/lib/cmake` and haven't found the file there either so I am kind back to square one as I can't find this specific file...

Comment: Try brute force: `find / -name QMainWindow *`. Then go for a coffee.

Comment: I found it....in `/usr/include/qt6/QtWidgets`
I set my include path to `/usr/include/qt6/**` but it still is not working which is lovely